# How can you handle dart exceptions that have been declared in a library?

Tags: flutter, dart

Trying to handle an exception in code below:

```dart
  findLocation() async {
    final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;

    try {
      gcd.locationFromAddress(userAddress).then((result) => controller
          .animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng(result[0].latitude, result[0].longitude),
              zoom: 15))));
    } on gcd.NoResultFoundException {
      print("test");
    }
  }
```

However, when this block runs unsuccessfully, it produces this error:

```
NoResultFoundException (Could not find any result for the supplied address or coordinates.)
```

The error points to this code block:

```
    switch (platformException.code) {
      case 'NOT_FOUND':
        throw NoResultFoundException();
    }
  }
```

NoResultFoundException is defined in a class with contents:

```
/// a [Placemark] from coordinates as [double] latitude and longitude
/// or [Location] from address as [String]
class NoResultFoundException implements Exception {
  /// Constructs the [LocationServiceDisabledException]
  const NoResultFoundException();

  @override
  String toString() =>
      'Could not find any result for the supplied address or coordinates.';
}
```

How can I handle this error in my `findLocation()` function?
(This is the flutter geocoding library by the way, and the exception is defined in the library files.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will only get exceptions if you `await` your call properly.

If you insist on using a `then` here, then you will need to use `.catchError` instead of a traditional try/catch block.

A word of advice, don't mix `await` and `then`. It's possible, but it's very easy to make mistakes. Stick with one, probably `await`, since it's easier to handle.

Comment: Thanks, do you think you could share a code block to let me know what to change? Or let me know? There is no specific need for then/CatchError